# Drupal, colocar o Web Form em cima do conteúdo.

Tags: html, css, drupal

Preciso fazer no tema do Drupal colocar este Web Form em cima do conteúdo ao invés de em baixo. Não sei como funciona o Drupal, porém eu tenho alguns conhecimentos de criação de templates Wordpress, eu abaixei o tema mas eu não sei qual arquivo eu devo alterar para que o Web Form fique em cima do arquivo.

Qual é o padrão do nome do arquivo? Como alterar isto este arquivo? Já tenho acesso ao tema, porém não sei aonde devo mudar.

Se for ajudar vocês o tema utilizado se chama **Professional Theme 7.x-2.04** Porém não acho que precise abaixar o tema para mudar pois acredito que os nomes dos arquivos deve ter um padrão. (Da mesma forma que o Wordpress) Me ajudem a achar.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É necessário alterar o alguns arquivos no tema que está usando.

1 - Crie uma nova região para o conteúdo que deseja, isso é feito no arquivo `seutema.info`

```
regions[conteudoantes]     = 'Itens exibidos antes do conteúdo principal'
```

2 - No arquivo `page.tpl.php` adicione a nova região

```
<?php
  print render($page['conteudoantes']); 
  print render($page['content']); 
?>
```

3 - nos blocos, adicione seu bloco do webform na nova região e salve.

4 - por garantia, limpe todos os caches

Answer (score 1):

No menu administrativo, acesse Estrutura e Blocos. Dentro de Blocos, existe na região Conteúdo um bloco chamado "Conteúdo da página principal". Veja se alterando a ordem dos blocos em Conteúdo você consegue o resultado que espera.

Comment: Eu fui em blocos e mudei o Web Form para content-top. Porém atualizer a página e o formulários está da mesma forma. Tentei abaixar o tema e mudar diretamente no tema, porém não achei nada que fazia referência ao web form.

Answer (score 0):

Eu não consegui fazer isto no próprio Drupal, porém eu ocultei as div do formulário, inspecionei o elemento, copiei o HTML e escrevi o formulário no próprio HTML das postagens.

Comment: assim não usou o drupal no final... para manter um histórico eu respondi aqui...